# VB 6: How many controls can I have on a single form?

Tags: vb6

I know the limit for named controls is 254, beyond that you have to use control arrays. But it seems we have hit the limit for arrays too. Any idea what that absolute limit is?

Comment: Maybe you should reevaluate your form design...

Comment: My goal is to replace the whole application, but we can't do that over night.

Comment: The exact number doesn't matter for this question I know, but the manual says the limit is 254 rather than 256 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240865(v=VS.60).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the correction and the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no *absolute* limit.  If you put enough controls on the form, you'll eventually run out of memory.  I made a test app that loads command buttons into a control array.  My first run stopped with an "Out of memory" error at around 6900 buttons.  I shut down a few other apps and was able to load nearly 8200.  I did the same thing with text boxes and got different results (about 7300 before and 8600 after).  Different controls consume different amounts of memory, so there really is no way to specify an exact number of controls that you can put on a form.

Answer (score 3):

We have a records management system written in VB6 and there is a UI guideline that says each record should have exactly one data entry form associated with it (i.e. can't open up other windows). As a result of this policy, one of the more complex record types in our system now has a form with a total of 659 individual controls. We had run into the 256 named controls limit, and then converted many of the controls to control arrays over time. Recently, we squeezed room for 5 or 6 new controls, after going through the entire form and converting the few remaining standalone controls to control arrays.

This is one time where I would like to break the rules, but that would involve quite a bit of refactoring to use a multiple form approach.

In any event, you can fit at least 659 controls on a form, but I've never been able to find out what the true absolute limit is (and I'm not sure that I want to).

Comment: I think we were over a thousand when we hit the hard limit, but I'm trying to find the exact number so that the business analysts know how much crude they have to remove from the next version.

Comment: If the form is close to the limit right now, you can add some code to the _Form_Load_ event to tell you how many controls are on the form right now, i.e. `MsgBox Me.Controls.Count`. Then you can try and add more controls until you hit the limit, then run the program and see what number you get back in the message box.

Comment: There definitely is a fixed limit of controls allowable per form unless they are array controls. I've just run into this issue :(