# reached limit cannot create any more controls for this form vb6

Tags: vb6

I am not able to create a new menu in my mdi form.As already so many existing menus are there.

Its giving error `"reached limit cannot create any more controls for this form"`.

Please help me to know that how to add new menu with this error.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265801(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134778/vb-6-how-many-controls-can-i-have-on-a-single-form

Answer (score 9):

You can use control arrays for your menus to overcome 256 controls per form limit. In Menu Editor you have to set `Index` property to an unique integer value to create control arrays of entries with same `Name`s.

A common strategy is to designate `mnuMain` name for a control array with top menus i.e. first `mnuMain(1)` would be "File", then `mnuMain(2)` would be "Edit", etc.

Then in form's code declare an enum like this

```
Private Enum MenuIndexesEnum
    idxFile = 1
    idxEdit
    idxTool
    ....
End Enum
```

and use it throughout code like `mnuMain(idxFile)` etc.

For "File" sub-menu designate `mnuFile` control array with unique indexes starting from 1 for "New", "Open", "Print", etc. "Exit" and extend the `MenuIndexesEnum` enum like this

```
Private Enum MenuIndexesEnum
    idxFile = 1
    idxEdit
    idxTool
    ....
    idxNew = 1
    idxOpen
    idxPrint
    idxExit = 99
    ...
End Enum
```

Then continue with `mnuEdit` for "Edit" sub-menu, etc.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299435/how-to-create-control-arrays-in-vb-net?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

As @wqw said, the problem is that you've reached the 256 controls-per-form limit, and the solution is to start wrapping them up into control arrays.  However, the control you're having an issue with (a menu) isn't necessarily the one you need to make into a control array.

I find that the most insidious, yet easiest to solve, control "consumers" are the label controls sprinkled everywhere on a typical form.  To turn those into a control array, I just adopted the practice of copying and pasting an existing label anytime I need a new one; the first time, VB will ask if you want to create a control array (say "Yes"), and thereafter it will automatically increment the index for you every time you create a new copy of the label.

For me, label controls are the most convenient to make into an array, because there's usually no code associated with them, and hence no need to worry about the index at all.